# How can I tell how much rep I lost to repcap in recent day(s)?

Tags: discussion, reputation

**How can I tell how much rep I lost to repcap in *recent* day(s)?** (less than 1 week ago)

@rand al'thor asked me that in comments, and I was at a loss how to answer.

I know how much rep I got from the rep tracker dropdown for any recent day.

I know I can calculate my total (ever) rep loss using Data.stackexchange.com queries, except that this data is 1 week old so I can't use it on recent week's days.

Is there a decent not-too-labour-intensive way for me to answer that question for a day in this week?

Comment: I tried writing some JavaScript to do this, but it didn't work out (because expanding line items is a server call). If you were technically inclined, you could write/run a Selenium script, I would think. I might try that tomorrow, actually. Sounds kind of fun

Comment: You can get a figure for how much rep you 'should' have got in 1 week (Sunday to Sunday) by getting the Data.SE figure for "[rep without rep cap](http://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/328997/rep-without-rep-cap-fixed-with-correct-answer-score)" and then getting it again on Sunday. The difference between these two figures will tell you how much rep you should have got between 20-27 Dec; subtract the amount you actually earned, and you'll find how much you lost to the repcap in that week. (I'm guessing about 5k.)

Comment: @randal'thor - post as an answer please

Comment: @DVK Right, done.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get a figure for how much rep you lost to the repcap in 1 week, Sunday to Sunday, as follows:

- visit [this page](http://data.stackexchange.com/scifi/query/328997/rep-without-rep-cap-fixed-with-correct-answer-score) at Data.SE to find out what your rep *would* have been last Sunday, 20 Dec at around 3am UTC, if not for the rep cap; the answer is **219322** rep
- visit the same page again next week to get a corresponding figure for next Sunday, 27 Dec at around 3am UTC; **EDIT:** I've now done this and found a figure of **229752** rep
- subtract the two figures
- PROFIT!!!

DVK, you earned ***10,000 rep*** in a single week between the 20th and 27th December. To quote @steelerfan: *faints, then explodes*!!!

Comment: My rep without the cap = 293980

Comment: @Richard - a really curious stat would be rep (sans cap) normalized by views, to account for NHQ (admittedly, I'd benefit far more than you, since my most active posting was during far less active site time AND before NHQ)

Comment: @DVK Are you sure? I've seen lots of old questions and answers with far higher scores than almost anything gets nowadays. Seems to be that as a site grows, it gets more traffic but also gets its questions more buried among other questions and maybe less massively upvoted. (See ELU.SE, which is bigger and older than SFF and where Great Question/Answer badges are vanishingly rare because there are so many crappy or mediocre questions posted every day they drown out the rare gems.) But then obviously you have far more and wider SE experience than I do!

Comment: @randal'thor - Movies:SE is a great current example. I've got some really solid answers there that are struggling to hit double figures. On SFF:SE, I'd expect them to be worth 50+

Comment: @randal'thor - there are some outliers but htey seem to be rare. Ask on meta, someone might find decents stats :)

Comment: @Richard maybe you have a bigger fanbase here than on M&TV? ;-)

Comment: @randal'thor - I think it's more to do with the fact that there are simply a lot fewer users.

Comment: @DVK You earned **10k** in a week. We are unworthy and grovel at your feet, O mighty one.

Answer (score 2):

When you repcap, your profile page's "reputation" activity still tracks your upvotes.

[image: RepCap example] [image: RepCap example]

If you change to [display the reputation by "post"](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/users/976/dvk?tab=reputation&sort=post):
[image: Post option]

Then you'll see exactly how many votes you received for a given question, whether or not it added to your reputation total, and can quick tally that up in your head or with a calculator.

[image]

Using this last method, you can easily construct a spreadsheet to tabulate your totals.

If you expand all the "# events" listed, you can then copy and paste the entire day's activity into Excel or Google Sheets, starting in A1.

Then, in the last column you can use a formula such as:

`=IF(AND(C2="upvote",ISBLANK(A2)),10,IF(AND(C2="upvote",MOD(A2,10)>0),10-MOD(A2,10),0))`

This formula performs the following:

```
if(activity == "upvote" && reputation.isBlank()) {
 return 10;
}
else if (activity == "upvote" && reputation % 10 > 0) {
 return 10 - reputation % 10; 
}
else { return 0;}
```

The `else if` accounts for partial rep gain earned because of downvotes.

Then, you do a simple `SUM()` of that new column, and you get, for example, 1417 lost reputation for @DVK on 2015-12-21 UTC.

I confirmed that the formula I posted works in both Excel and Google Sheets, but I don't know if it works in OpenCalc/LibreCalc/Numbers.

Comment: Methinks you underestimate [how much activity DVK has](http://scifi.stackexchange.com/users/976/dvk?tab=reputation&sort=post)

Comment: @JasonBaker I linked right to it! It's easy to see on a daily basis. You could make an Excel sheet to count it easily enough!

Comment: Whoops, didn't see that. I mean, this *is* the only way, but I think it fails the "labour-intensivity" test

Comment: @JasonBaker - Yeah. I was definitely rejecting this specific method mentally when I was writing that "labour intensive" caveat. Doesn't mean it isn't the only option, unfortunately :(

Comment: @DVK I built a small spreadsheet formula that does the trick. The slowest part of the process is expanding your "# events" activities. If you do this, start from the *bottom*, so the page doesn't keep pushing down your next target. Sorry you lost more rep yesterday than I earned last week.

Comment: @JasonBaker - almost 90 posts had votes on them in 24h period 2 days ago. Whoah, in the immortal wise words of Keanu Reaves

Answer (score 1):

Since I recently found myself with a whole mess of free time, I thought I'd take a stab at this. So I wrote a small webapp using the [StackExchange API](http://api.stackexchange.com):

### [SE Rep Loss Calculator](https://se-rep-loss-calculator.herokuapp.com)

It's still a work-in-progress, but it seems to more-or-less work for the time being. A few remarks and caveats:

- It's (in theory) somewhat of an improvement over the SEDE query in [Rand al'thor's answer](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/a/7781/31051):

  - It's updated in real-time, so you don't have to worry about the SEDE update delay
  - It accounts for reputation lost from *your* votes, not just other people voting on your posts
  - It also accounts for reputation from non-vote sources: things like suggested edits, deleted posts, bounties, and so on
- Because it takes into account things like reputation gained/lost from you downvoting posts (which isn't visible to people other than you and SE employees), you need to log into the application with your SE credentials. I (meaning, the application) use the [authentication protocol provided by the API](http://api.stackexchange.com/docs/authentication), but I do request access to private information (it wouldn't work at all otherwise). I can't use this to impersonate you, or read your global inbox, but I can and do use it to look at basically your entire up- and down-voting history.

  Now, I (as myself, not the app) can't actually see *any* of this. All of the processing happens on your computer, so even if I wanted to save and inspect this information, I couldn't. The app is also open source, so you're welcome to [take a look at the code](https://github.com/jwbaker/se-rep-loss-calculator) to ensure that I'm not doing anything untoward with the access tokens. That said, it does require a little bit of trust. If you *don't* trust me, it is possible to run this application on your local computer, but it's a bit of a pain.
- Because of a bug I haven't quite figured out yet, the reputation counters don't reset every time you click the button; so if you want to re-calculate, you'll need to reload the page. I'm working on that.
- You also need to re-login on every page load, because I don't store the access token. I'm not sure if that's a bug or a feature.
- I'm running the app on a free Heroku account, so it may not be available 100% of the time. If it's not available when you want it, try again later
- Bear in mind that I'm limited to 10,000 API calls per day, and the number of calls per click grows quite substantially the longer your time period is, or the more reputation you gain per day<sup>1</sup>. Be kind: don't spam the "calculate" button.
- I've done very little testing of this. It should work for most things, but there may be some weird edge cases I can't replicate
- <s>If</s> *When* you run into problems, kindly either post a comment here, or [file a bug on GitHub](https://github.com/jwbaker/se-rep-loss-calculator/issues) and I'll look into it

---

<sup>1</sup> *Every* calculation takes at least two calls: one to authenticate you, and at least one to retrieve your reputation history. Because I can only retrieve up to 100 items with a single call, I may need lots of calls to get your entire reputation history.

In addition, in order to distinguish between votes on questions and votes on answers (which affect your rep in different ways), I need to ask the API for information on *each* post you've received rep for; again, I can only get up to 100 of these at a time (although I'm a little smart; I don't ask for the same post more than once), so receiving rep on more than 100 unique posts will cause more calls.